# How to increase throughput of Boost ASIO, UDP client application

Tags: c++, asynchronous, boost, udp, synchronous

I am using the Boost ASIO library to implement a Windows UDP client which needs to be capable of high throughput.

I would like to use asynchronous receive calls so that I can eventually implement a receive timeout, ie. after a certain amount of time if no datagrams have been received my application will exit.

My problem is that I see 30% higher data throughput using synchronous receives
vs. asynchronous receives. I have observed this issue when running the
application on multiple Dell R630, R710 Windows 2008 Servers, and even my
Lenovo ThinkPad laptop.

*What are the main performance differences between the two code segments below?
Is there more overhead in calling `ioService.run_one()` after each async receive?
I am a new user of the Boost library, so any help would be much appreciated!*

Synchronous Receive:

```
socket_->receive_from(boost::asio::buffer(&vector_[0], datagramSize),  
                      endPoint_);
```

vs.

Asynchronous Receive (with blocking):

```
err = boost::asio::error::would_block;

socket_->async_receive_from(
    boost::asio::mutable_buffers_1(&vector_[0], datagramSize),
    endPoint_,
    boost::bind(&HandleRead, _1, _2, &err, &bytesReceived));

do
{
    ioService_.run_one()
}
while(err == boost::asio::error::would_block)
```

Asynchronous Receive Handler Function:

```
static void HandleRead
(
    const boost::system::error_code& error, 
    std::size_t bytesRead,
    boost::system::error_code* outError, 
    std::size_t* outBytesRead
)
{
    *outError = error;
    *outBytesRead = bytesRead;
}
```

Comment: In your async_receive_from case, handler is allocated with slow standard `operator new`. Fast [custom allocation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/asio_handler_allocate.html) of handler would improve performance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It shouldn't come as a surprise that the *`async_`* family of API functions has as most important property that they run *asynchronously*.

Running anything *asynchronously* is not - by itself - going to make it faster. In fact, due to scheduling artefacts it might be slower.

The thing is that asynchrony can allow you to do many more things on a small number of threads (e.g. the main thread).

It sounds a little bit as if your application doesn't require that multiplexing kind of operation. If your application indeed consumes a single source of packets as fast as possible in a linear fashion, than indeed it makes no sense to

- interpose a (thread safe) task queue
- ask `io_service` to schedule the tasks across the available service threads¹ (you have only one)
- coordinate the results back in the form of callbacks; The callbacks frequently lead to object lifetime hacks, which in turn frequently lead to `shared_ptr<>`s. If so, these are all sources of more delays (due to reduced locality of reference, more dynamic allocations etc.).

Don't use asynchronous mode if you don't need it.

Even if you have a limited number of essentially single-threaded, sequential running tasks, you can probably achieve the most by having a thread for each, a `io_service` per thread and avoid the coordination.

¹ threads running `io_service::run` or similar